# What's the difference between "winding up" and "winding down"?

Tags: meaning, differences

Can they be used interchangeably (like "fat chance" and "slim chance")? Or do they mean something different?

Comment: I don't think you can always interchange them. I only ever hear of companies being wound up rather than down.

Answer (score 1):

Winding up has a second meaning, to antagonize or troll.

But yes, I think they are similar when used to refer to something coming to an end.  Perhaps wind up sounds more like things should come to a stop, whereas wind down sounds more like a gradual reduction of activity.  But if you give the order, "Ok kids, let's wind things ____ in here" then both would be similarly understood.

Comment: Second meaning to what? Perhaps you could add where 'wind up' and 'wind down' mean the same, for the sake of completion.